# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Coordinate out of bounds

Tags: java

```
public static int[] getPixelData(BufferedImage img, int x, int y)

{

int argb = img.getRGB(x, y);

int rgb[] = new int[] 

{

((argb >> 16) & 0xfe), //red

(argb >>  8) & 0xfe, //green

(argb      ) & 0xfe  //blue

};

System.out.println("rgb: " + Integer.toBinaryString(rgb[0]) + " " + Integer.toBinaryString(rgb[1]) + " " +Integer.toBinaryString(rgb[2]));





return rgb;


}
```

o/p

> rgb:  10111000    11010010   11110110
>        rgb: 10111010 11011010 11111100
>        rgb: 10101110 11010100 11110010
>        rgb: 10100010 11010000 11100110
>        rgb: 10100000 11010100 11100000
>        rgb: 10011110 11010110 11010100
>        rgb: 10011110 11011000 11001110
>        rgb: 10011110 11011000 11001110

and here is the exception

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   Coordinate out of bounds!
>        at sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster.getDataElements(Unknown Source)
>        at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getRGB(Unknown Source)
>        at get_pixel_value.getPixelData(get_pixel_value.java:52)
>        at get_pixel_value.get_pixel_info(get_pixel_value.java:28)
>        at Hash_Function2.main(Hash_Function2.java:26)

how could i remove this exception

Comment: The exception happens in your method getPixelData() that is not posted. Please send it. And probably remove irrelevant code that you already sent.

Comment: Please edit your original post and show any new code or changed code in the edit. As you can see, you cannot post readable code in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

the value of k should be less than 3 and not rgb.length since you defined

```
int[][] pixelData = new int[img.getHeight() * img.getWidth()]  [3];
```

Or if rgb.length is correct, you need to change the array size accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
img = ImageIO .read(new File(IMG));
int[][] pixelData = new int[img.getHeight() * img.getWidth()][];
for(int i = 0; i < img.getHeight(); i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < img.getWidth(); j++) {
        pixelData[i*img.getWidth()+j] = getPixelData(img, i, j);

    }
}

...

public static int[] getPixelData(BufferedImage img, int x, int y) {
    int argb = img.getRGB(x, y);
    int rgb[] = new int[] {
        ((argb >> 16) & 0xff), //red 
        (argb >> 8) & 0xff, //green
        (argb ) & 0xff //blue
    }
    return rgb;
}
```

But you can also get an rgb array from a BufferedImage directly.
There is a second getRGB method.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html

Comment: In which line does the exception occur?

Comment: dnt know, but according to the stack trace line no 53 ie above code